# Recurring job in Hangfire not running for a specific hour?

Tags: .net, hangfire, .net-6.0

I'm newbie to hangfire and I try a basic recurrent job (on Console app) like this

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                .UseSqlServerStorage("Server=.\\sqlexpress;Database=HangfireTest;Integrated Security=SSPI;");

            using (var server = new BackgroundJobServer())
            {
               
                RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("LiveFixtures", () => Console.WriteLine("hello"), "0-59 * * * *");
                Console.WriteLine("Hangfire Server started. Press any key to exit...");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
```

It works fine, however if I try with a specific hour, both of the following lines fail to work. The current time is 11:19 AM

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("LiveFixtures", () => Console.WriteLine("hello"), "0-59 11 * * *");
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("LiveFixtures", () => Console.WriteLine("hello"), "0-59 10-23 * * *");
```

Comment: I guess Hangfire uses UTC by default. Depending on your time zone, and the moment you test your coade, it may be the cause of your problem.

Comment: thanks, I get it work with TimeZoneInfo.Local

Comment: thanks for the follow-up. I posted an answer

Answer (score 0):

Hangfire uses UTC by default. Depending on your time zone, and the moment you test your code, it may be the cause of your problem.

As you already mentionned in the comments, the following should work :

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("LiveFixtures", () => Console.WriteLine("hello"), "0-59 11 * * *", TimeZoneInfo.Local);
```